# RecursiveLinkedCollection and remove method java

Tags: java

for one of my lab homework I have to create a recRemove method that removes a node from a linked list. Here is the work that I have done so far:

```
private LLNode<T> recRemove(LLNode<T> node, T data) {
    if(node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if(node == data) {
        LLNode<T> temp = new LLNode<T>(data);
        node = temp;
        temp.setLink(node.getLink());
    }
    return recRemove(node.getLink(), data);
}


@Override
public boolean remove(T data) {
    recRemove(front, data);
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the returned Node from recRemove into a boolean. I get an error from this line:

```
  recRemove(front, data);
```

also, here is the remove method that is implemented from the CollectionInterface:

```
 /**
 * Removes element if found
 * @param element
 * @return true if found and removed, otherwise false
 */ 

boolean remove(T element);
```

Comment: Why do you create a new node? Also, the description at the end sounds more like a "contains" function than a "remove".

Comment: so should it just be 'node.setLink(node.getLink())'?

Comment: and that was my bad, i updated the description.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(node == data)` check for the value of `node` instead (also probably using `equals` instead of `==`)? Also it seems you are not updating the predecessor of `node` to correctly point to `temp` (respectively change the value of `front`) after removing a node. And currently your code would remove all occurences of a value (in case there a multiple) if that is intended it would be good to add that to the javadoc of your `remove` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove node from linked list recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321983/remove-node-from-linked-list-recursively)

Answer (score 0):

With recursion, it often helps to start with the simplest case. Usually the recursive definition of a list is `head :: tail`, i.e. the first element of the list followed by the rest of the list. Conveniently, a linked list is pretty much modeled like this (`node` is the head, and `getNext()` points to the tail).

Our recursive remove function will always return the head of the *new list*.

So the simplest case of removing an element from the list is removing from an empty list:

```
if (node == EMPTY) return EMPTY;
```

(`EMPTY` is a constant tag for the end of the list. It can be modeled using `null` in Java)

The second simplest case is if the head is already the element which needs to be removed:

```
if (Objects.equals(node.value(), data)) {
    return node.next();
}
```

That leaves the case where the node to remove potentially exists in the tail:

```
return new Node(node.value(), recRemove(node.next(), data));
```

Putting it all together:

```
Node<T> recRemove(Node<T> node, T value) {
    if (node == EMPTY) return EMPTY;
    if (Objects.equals(node.value(), data)) return node.next();
    return new Node<T>(node.value(), recRemove(node.next(), data));
}
```